# Problem with moderncv

Tags: pdf, miktex, moderncv

[image]I have been trying to write a CV with LaTeX following this tutorial :

https://www.baeldung.com/cs/latex-moderncv-resume

The commands given in the tutorial to install MiKTeX didn't work in my command prompt so instead I used the assistant to install it with TeXworks. I also installed all suggested packages including moderncv. Then I started the CV but when I tried to compile it in order to get a PDF I got nothing except the errors you can see right below :

```
Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \@firstname 
            {}~\@lastname {}
l.7 \begin{document}
```

Here is the code I've written so far (without personal data) :

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, draft, unicode]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme{casual}
\moderncvcolor{grey}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\recomputelengths
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}

\firstname{}
\lastname{}

\title{Computer science student}

\mobile{}
\email{}
\address{}

\social[linkedin]{}
\social[github]{Arraymanios}
\social[stackoverflow]{Areimanios}

\section{Computer skills}
\cvdoubleitem{category 1}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 4}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\cvdoubleitem{category 2}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 5}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\cvdoubleitem{category 3}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 6}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}

\end{document}
```

Do you have any idea to fix the problem please ?

Comment: Welcome. // Which problem do you still face? // Unfortunately your posted code is far away from a successful compile ... kindly follow https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10137/245790 to provide code we can use. Thank you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: the tex error message marks which command is undefined by adding a line break, but you have wrapped the message and placed it in a quote which makes it hard to read, always use a code block so line endings are preeserved in messages

Comment: but if I try to reconstruct the original message it seems `\phantomsection ` is undefined so add `\usepackage{hyperref}`

Comment: "Class moderncv Warning: "academicons requires xetex/luatex to work. Using
 alternatives."." means you should use lualatex not pdflatex as the command

Comment: @David Carlisle

Hello sir, I did as you suggested and I also added \begin{document} and \end{document} but it generated another error message referencing hyperref :

! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package hyperref.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.9 \begin{document}
                  
?

Comment: @David Carlisle Removing "\usepackage{hyperref}" gives the following error :

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \@firstname 
            {}~\@lastname {}
l.8 \begin{document}
                  
?

I am using LuaLaTeX to compile this time, I don't really know what to do at this point.

Comment: You have not provided any code that produces the error that you show, so it os very hard to guess any help.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Hello sir, I just edited the question updating both the 
LaTeX code and the corresponding error. I also used LuaLaTeX to compile it but it didn't work.

I also added a screenshot to prove I get the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define your name (to empty) too late. As the error shows, it is used in `\begin{document}` in this class:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \@firstname 
            {}~\@lastname {}
l.7 \begin{document}
```

So define it before then. This runs without error.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, draft, unicode]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme{casual}
\moderncvcolor{grey}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\recomputelengths
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\firstname{}
\lastname{}
\begin{document}

\title{Computer science student}

\mobile{}
\email{}
\address{}

\social[linkedin]{}
\social[github]{Arraymanios}
\social[stackoverflow]{Areimanios}

\section{Computer skills}
\cvdoubleitem{category 1}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 4}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\cvdoubleitem{category 2}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 5}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\cvdoubleitem{category 3}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 6}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello sir, problem is solved. Thank you very much. :)